# Form Data in HTTP Post arrives empty

Tags: android, asp.net, http, post

I have been looking at this for several days now and still unable to resolve.  Perhaps there is some recommended reading I could go to that will help me improve my base understanding and address what I have missed.

Android:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
context.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.11:56050/Account/LoginNonWeb.aspx");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", mEmail));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", mPassword));

try {
    UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, HTTP.UTF_8);
    entity.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, context);
    ...
    }
```

ASP.Net:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) //check if the webpage is loaded for the first time.
    {
        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection postedValues = Request.Form;
        foreach (string key in postedValues)
        {
            var value = postedValues[key];
            value = postedValues[key];

        }
        String loginEmail = postedValues["email"];
        String loginPassword = postedValues["password"];
    }
}
```

When the page loads `Request.Form` is always empty.  With the content type of the post and entity being `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` I was expecting it to be populated.

Comment: Well tell if you have errors/exceptions on Android side first. Look in the logcat of the IDE. It tells you all. From where and how do you call this upload code? Using device or emulator?

Comment: `When the page loads`. What do you mean exactly? `Request.Form is always empty`. Where do you see that? Is Page_Load() called? What is the value of `IsPostBack` then?

Comment: No exceptions thrown, the post is called in an async thread running the app in debug on the device.  The response is 200.  I will look in logcat.  I assume for now it's straight forward to find out how to do that and to interpret what's in there.

Comment: Think you have to change `if(!IsPostBack)`  to `if (IsPostBack)`.

Comment: That condition is always true and the block is entered where request.form is read.

Comment: Page_load is called (!ispostback) is true and request.Form is examined in this true block and found to be empty.  The post returns a response status 200.

Comment: Do a sanity check and check the Request (e.g. `Request.RequestType`) just to make sure your Java client is actually sending a `POST` with data...or you can `curl` the same aspx target. If `curl` works, then it's the client...Hth...

Comment: `The post returns a response status 200.` That only tells that the webserver could find the script. It tells nothing about what the script did. For that to know you have to let the script return data. And you should read that data in the client. Normally some html source would be returned after a post.

Comment: @EdSF thank you I appreciate your advice. It did not occur to me to check the request type since I was using httppost in the android client. Turned out my code was receiving a GET, but a POST was being sent, just the server was responding 301 due to the unnecessary *.aspx and the android Apache client was automatically re-requesting for the right URL but with a GET not a POST.

Comment: Cool - that would also have been discovered with `curl`. I recall getting bit by something similar in the past because a WebForms site had "extensionless urls" (which does 301) if you request a `.aspx` resource (client gets redirected to extensionless resource).

Comment: Unfortunately it won't let me vote on your comment.  Maybe if you give an answer I can mark it answered.  Sorry.